# Как правильно вызвать и получить данные из конвейерной (pipelined) функции?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

Подскажите, как правильно получить данные в WebJava имея такую pipelined функцию:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE info_pkg AS 

TYPE info IS RECORD{
  description VARCHAR2(30),
  task NUMBER,
  e_time DATE
};

TYPE infos IS TABLE OF info; 

FUNCTION get_tasks (id IN NUMBER, name IN VARCHAR2, timestamp IN DATE)
RETURN info_pkg.infos
PIPELINED;

END info_pkg;
```

Простые процедуры вызывать умею, на SQL*Plus эта функция работает.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410452/fetch-oracle-table-type-from-stored-procedure-using-jdbc) и версию укажите.

Comment: Спасибо. Использую Oracle EE 9.2. По ссылке вроде есть какое то решение, но с написанием программы на Java на сервере БД. А мне необходимо на WebJava через JDBC драйвер.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что там на сервере? Как раз клиентские примеры c idbc. Я WebJava не знаю, есть какие-то существенные отличия?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конвейерные (*pipelined*) функции нельзя вызывать в PL/SQL контексте как обычные функции.
Поэтому, их надо вызывать обычным SQL запросом с оператором `table`:

```java
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class TestCallFunc {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@srv/svc", "me", "me");
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement (
                "select * from table (info_pkg.get_tasks (?, ?, ?))");
            ps.setInt (1, 1);
            ps.setString (2, "Task");
            ps.setDate (3, new java.sql.Date (new java.util.Date().getTime()));
            ResultSet rset = ps.executeQuery ();
            while (rset.next ()) {
                System.out.println (
                    rset.getInt ("task")+"\t"+
                    rset.getString ("description")+"\t"+
                    rset.getDate ("dt")); }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
10      Task1   2020-06-25
20      Task2   2020-06-26
30      Task3   2020-06-27
```

---

PS Код из вопроса не полный и не рабочий, поэтому [привожу рабочий код](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ebe87f7e6d7a4a30ef4c646636b9233e) для примера.